# Running extract method refactoring from commande line

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I wanted to know please, if it is possible to run Refactor plugin (https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-ExtractMethod.htm) from command line or from source code. In other words, I want to automatize the refactoring. Thank you very much.

Comment: No it can't be run from the command line. You might be able to run the refactor operation from another plugin but it would take a lot of research.

Comment: Do you think that it would be easier to develop my own refactoring plugin and run it as I want?

Comment: Refactoring is not easy whichever way you do it. You would have to understand  the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) in detail.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please tell me how can I run the refactor operation from another plugin or show me where possibly I can find a solution. In fact, I am developing a plugin in which the first step is to refactor the source code. So if I can run the refactor operation from my plugin, it would be perfect. Note that, I work on code analysis, so I understand JDT Abstract Syntax Tree.

Comment: Like I said that would take a lot of research, by which I mean reading the JDT source code. Starting with `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.ExtractMethodAction`

Comment: Thank you for your help.